# Android Studio:disable "never used" warning on methods that I want to use later

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I've beginning (but not finished) to implement a method that i want to use later.
Is there a way to say (perphaps via a comment) to Android Studio to no warn for this specific method with "never used" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void myMethod(){...}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unused") did not work for me, but @Suppress("unused") did.